# why the last computed item in a stream doesn't appear in REPL?

Tags: scala, stream, read-eval-print-loop

Lately, I've run a few tests on stream in the REPL and strangely the last computed item in the stream isn't displayed. Example of what I mean:

```
val s = Stream.from(1)
// scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

s(5)
// Int = 6

s
// scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ?)
```

Maybe I am missing something, but I would expect `s` to contain 6 (i.e. `s(5)`). 
Can anyone explain this?

[scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_91)]

Comment: strange, it appears in scala 2.11.7 (oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in scala 2.11.6 which has been fixed for 2.11.7

See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9219 for more details